# How to select elements using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have table where I want to iterate over rows (tr) in root tbody and not rows in it child

I try this but with no success:

```
Elements tableRows = table.select("tr");
```

this get tr also in it child so I have there duplicates

```
Elements tableRows = table.select("tbody > td:first-child");
```

this doesnt work too

here is my table:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%" align="center">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="head">Rank</td>
   <td class="Head">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="Lhead">Club</td>
   <td class="head">Nation</td>
   <td class="head">Rank points</td>
   <td class="head">Five best results (by points)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="playerB">60. (1.)</td>
   <td class="Lplayer"><a href="player.aspx?id=260161">Imrich Blasko</a></td>
   <td class="Lplayer"><a href="club.aspx?id=260008">THC Blue Dragon Kosice</a></td>
   <td class="player"><img src="flags/SVK.gif" alt="SVK" /></td>
   <td class="playerB">3&nbsp;398</td>
   <td class="Lplayer">
    <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td class="Lplayer"><a href="tournament.aspx?id=14379">World Championships 2013</a></td>
       <td class="Rplayer">817</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="Lplayer"><a href="tournament.aspx?id=14192">Czech Open 2012</a></td>
       <td class="Rplayer">674</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="Lplayer"><a href="tournament.aspx?id=15844">Czech Open 2013</a></td>
       <td class="Rplayer">668</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="Lplayer"><a href="tournament.aspx?id=16982">Slovak Championships 2013</a></td>
       <td class="Rplayer">621</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="Lplayer"><a href="tournament.aspx?id=17781">Bratislava Cup 2013</a></td>
       <td class="Rplayer">617</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="6">
    <hr color="#008080" width="100%" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="playerB">159. (2.)</td>
   <td class="Lplayer"><a href="player.aspx?id=650633">Tibor Valachovic ml.</a></td>
   <td class="Lplayer"><a href="club.aspx?id=260007">SHK Skalica</a></td>
   <td class="player"><img src="flags/SVK.gif" alt="SVK" /></td>
   <td class="playerB">2&nbsp;847</td>
   <td class="Lplayer">
    <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td class="Lplayer"><a href="tournament.aspx?id=15844">Czech Open 2013</a></td>
       <td class="Rplayer">639</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="Lplayer"><a href="tournament.aspx?id=16318">Brno 2013</a></td>
       <td class="Rplayer">594</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="Lplayer"><a href="tournament.aspx?id=17784">Brno 2014</a></td>
       <td class="Rplayer">583</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="Lplayer"><a href="tournament.aspx?id=16982">Slovak Championships 2013</a></td>
       <td class="Rplayer">569</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="Lplayer"><a href="tournament.aspx?id=12576">Czech Open 2011</a></td>
       <td class="Rplayer">461</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="6">
    <hr color="#008080" width="100%" /></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Elements tableRows = table.select(":root > tbody > tr");
```

Comment: I didn't know the :root selector. Nice! But what if the table is not the root of the document?

Comment: What about something like this: "table:not(td > table) > tbody > tr"? It selects only the non-nested tables.